# How to add a jar package to project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have added to my pom.xml a  section that specifies the mainClass and allows it to essentially create an executable jar.  I have included a bunch of dependencies that maven manages as well.  It executes fine, but fails to run when it gets to a section of code that needs to know the location of a jar package that was made inhouse by somebody (i.e., not from Maven).  In the project in eclipse I had put the jar in src/lib and my code is in src/main/java.  I had to select properties and Java Build Path and specify there the src/lib location for the jar to get it to even compile.  However, trying to run java -jar name.jar has it fail and complain because it fails to import the classes from the src/lib jar.  Since it is not a maven thing, how to I make sure this is a dependency for this project and that it is seen on the project's classpath?

Comment: 'src/lib' doesn't sound that great. Either it is source or libraries. Not both. But it wasn't me downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with maven is that maven has to control all of the dependencies and that includes this jar you want to reference.  That doesn't mean that you have to build that other jar using maven, you could mvn install it in your local repository or use a tool like Artifactory to put it in a private remote repository. I know that installing regular jars via Artifactory creates a pom file for the jar and from then on you can treat the jar like any other maven dependency.

Comment: I was not sure how to mvn install this if i do not know what to use for artifactid.